# Draw engine to create a post-it and save the image

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I'm looking for a client-side draw-engine. I would prefer JavaScript and want to reach a maximum of browser-compatibility.

Is there any engine out there?

The user should be able to draw on a post-it (as a background) and save this img.

Comment: Have you done any research yourself?  Please use Google to do a little legwork.

Comment: I have done aa research but i found nothing suitable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with HTML5 canvas or maybe SVG. There's a number of frameworks available already. http://www.backslash.gr/content/blog/webdevelopment/7-10-javascript-canvas-frameworks

Comment: Thank you, but all examples show, how to build shapes for e.g. In a svg and not a simple draw engine to draw lines by the mouse